# Display records side by side

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I use a DataTable to bind my crystal report. It contains columns for credit and debit. If either one is zero, so is the other. Therefore every column contains either credit or debit information. I want to display something like:

```
Bank Name(Credit)|CreditAmt|BankName(Debit)|DebitAmt
```

My first column needs to display credit records with the bank name, and the second column displays Credit Amount and same logic for Debit amount - which displays in 3rd and 4th column.

My output currently looks like:

> - HDFC Bank | 550 |(blank) | 0
> - blank)          | 0   | 500 |    HDFc bank

I get blank a space and 0 in any section either credit or debit - because I only get the credit or debit amount per record. Therefore it puts 0 and blank spaces for other sections. How can I suppress th blank section to look like the following?

> - HDFC Bank | 550 |(blank) | 500 |HDFc bank

Comment: How these fields look like in your Data Table ??

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is summarize your transactions by a common column to both your Debit and Credit.  I assume **Bank Name** is the common link.  Then summarize your Debit and Credit. Here are the steps to take:

1. Menu Insert->Group (Select the column common to your Dr. and Cr.)
2. Menu Insert->Summary (Select your Dr. Column and use SUM)
3. Place the results on the Group Header line
4. Menu Insert->Summary (Select your Cr. Column and use SUM)
5. Place the results on the Group Header line
6. Hide your details line

Now to further your understanding of what we are doing here, suppose you wanted to summarize by the accounts per bank.  You'd do step 1, then insert another group by Account and then add the summarized Dr. & Cr. to the Account Group Header.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping solution is great.

Another possible solution is:
- creating a formula field called `NextDebit` that gets `Debit` value from the next line `Next(Debit)`
- show in Detail Section `Credit` and `NextDebit`
- suppress details where `Credit = 0`

Another solution i working on the query, so that you'll have just the data you need in the way you need to work on.